# How to sync local storage with firebase db angular?

Tags: angular

I'm fetching all the data from API and setting that data in local storage. All works fine.

Now the problem is, If any new items added from the backend, How do I update my local storage to display the newly added item ?

Below is my code,

Getting All members from Firebase DB

```
   firebase.database().ref('coremembers').on("value", snap => {
      let data = snap.val();
      if (data) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
          this.members.push(data[key]);
        });
        this.filteredMembers = this.members;
        localStorage.setItem("members", JSON.stringify(this.filteredMembers));
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    });
```

On click of the favorite button, adding the member to `favoriteMembers`

```
  toggleFav(member) {
    member.favorite = !member.favorite;
    let members = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("members"));
    this.favoriteMembers = members.filter(item => item.favorite === true);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<a (click)="toggleFav(member)" *ngIf="member.favorite; else elseFav"
                      class="open-popup shopfav"><img src="assets/fav_a.png" alt="" title="">
</a>
<ng-template #elseFav>
   <a (click)="toggleFav(member)" class="open-popup shopfav"><img src="assets/fav.png" alt="" title=""> </a>
</ng-template>
```